# Why localhost and online out are totally different

Tags: php

I have a login system, the code is like :
include('db.php');

```
        $result = mysql_query("select id,username,password from user_data 
        where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
    if($result)
        {   
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        { /// access the login page }
   else{ header('Location:index.php?error=wrong');
        exit();}}
```

I create 3 password

```
 username, pass
 1.admin,  aaa
 2.user01,  user01
 3.user02,  user02
```

It works fine in localhost with all password n in my site it works by only one username and password `i.e admin,  aaa`.
 Remaining second and third user, pass I can't login. **No errors are generated**

Comment: Try to update the query as "select id,username,password from user_data 
        where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'"

Comment: mysql_* functions no longer support by php use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh ok thanks for reminding me, bt i use mysq_* function in whole project. It works when first username n pass is given

Comment: ok @yank can u try with trim($password)? may be spacing issue

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh no it donot works

Comment: Output of `var_dump(result);` in localhost is `resource(5) of type (mysql result)` and site is `resource(3) of type (mysql result)`

Comment: there is also a error but may it's not  your solution you are closing if } in comments @yank

Comment: no no i donot mention } in my question, bt I there is } in code. Missing } is a fatal error it will halt n show error otherwise

Comment: it donot outputs anythng of `var_dump(result);` if user are user01 n user02 and pass user01 n user02 receptively

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)` also false except username n password are admin and aaa